# What can I do with [Ingredient] off-topic but not mentioned in Help/on-topic

Tags: discussion

We have a clear close reason for questions asking what to do with an ingredient.

> Questions of the form "What can I do with [ingredient]?" are off-topic because they are subjective and lead to a long list of equally good suggestions, which is not compatible with the Stack Exchange format. See [Culinary Uses Guidelines](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/740) for details. Exceptions are made for items which are not generally considered to have any culinary use.

…and yet this is not disclosed in advance should a user look at our on-topic Help page - [What topics can I ask about here?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

I was just about to slap my 'helpful advice' boilerplate on a question I voted to close this morning

> Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

…but realised it's just not covered.

Can we add it to the Help - or remove it from the close reasons? One or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, your question has a positive score and nobody has objected. By Meta rules, this constitutes agreement, so I edited our list of off-topic questions to include the bullet

> Suggestions how to use an ingredient (I need ideas for savory dishes made with pumpkin)

The formulation need not be final, we can discuss it further here or in a new Meta question.

Comment: Simple & to the point. Works for me if no-one comes up with further suggestions.