# Is cooking too subjective to work?

Tags: discussion, subjectivity

I received an email which specifically cited cooking as an example of a Stack Exchange site that "is awful". This person said:

> Meta-judgement is the ability to assess the quality of someone else's contribution. Different people have different meta-judgement skills in different areas. Wikipedia has been largely successful because they've carefully circumscribed out the area of knowledge in which people's meta-judgement skills are reasonably good (no original research, neutral point of view, verifiability etc.). Stack Overflow has also been successful because objective programming questions are also an area where people's meta-judgement abilities are good.
>
> Once you move out of these carefully circumscribed areas, I think you run into trouble with your philosophy.
>
> I've been casually lurking on the cooking stack exchange for a while. It's awful. The people there don't know [anything] and they don't even know enough to recognize the people who do know [anything]. As someone who is a damn good cook, I look around for a bit and I can't see a compelling reason for me to contribute in such a community. There's a thousand other places I could go to throw my pearls of wisdom into an indifferent crowd, the cooking stack exchange is no different from any of the rest of them.

I am not saying I agree with this, I am presenting it for your feedback.

It's true that **we explicitly disallowed subjective questions for a long time**, and for good reason. But we have learned that it *is* possible to have constructive, useful Q&A around totally subjective topics. To that end, we came up with [the Six Guidelines for Great Subjective Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

It's hard to address this argument in detail without specific examples of these bad cooking questions and answers, so in Wikipedia parlance, `{{citation needed}}`.

But I guess the crux of it, as stated, is that cooking is a topic where this "meta-judgement" ability is in particularly short supply.

Your thoughts? And let's fill in the missing citations: what are the *best* and *worst* examples of cooking questions on the site, right now?

> worst as in "most highly upvoted but objective wrong answer" and best as in "most downvoted/argued against but actually objectively correct" answer.

Comment: *"I've been casually lurking on the cooking stack exchange for a while. It's awful. The people there don't know [anything] and they don't even know enough to recognize the people who do know [anything]. As someone who is a damn good cook"* ... Umm. There are quite a few professionals here, self included, and the community seems to by and large recognise that.

Comment: Could you state your credentials? I couldn't find them anywhere on your profile.

Comment: You know, after reading all of the follow-up comments (still without *one single* example), I'm starting to suspect that we've all been the victims of a very elaborate trolling attempt.

Comment: and/or he is attempting to position himself as more experienced/knowledgeable than e.g. you, darin, papin, hobodave, or michael. (aside: it seems to be kind of a sausage party around here. while in a strict sense, gender is irrelevant and only knowledge/skill matters, are we making this place less welcoming for women?)

Comment: @Aaronut - an elaborate trolling example that might some day allow the troll to post something to his blog about this whole incident, thus perhaps upping his reputation as an SME on not food, but social networks.  At least that's my theory.  @roux - there was a meta thread on making it welcoming for all classes of people a while back

Comment: @roux: I, personally, am not a professional of any sort, just an enthusiast, so if he wants to make that claim on me, all he has to do is show evidence of *any* professional experience.  You, Darin, papin, Michael, etc. are another story entirely.

Comment: @justkt: Very interesting theory. It is conspicuous how quickly he managed to work in the link to his blog and his favourite communities. I am not an SME on social networking either but did read his post from top to bottom and was rather underwhelmed; it's full of specious reasoning from the very first paragraph (I can point to several people who are incredibly intelligent, valuable friends and yet still enjoy both talking and meeting people). The entire essay seems to be little more than a defense of elitism, peppered with occasional bragging about his "insider" status in various communities.

Comment: @roux Re gender disparity, I'm willing to bet that the vast majority of users here came from StackOverflow.  Cooking has inherited SO's user set, which is pretty far away from 50/50.

Answer (score 17):

I don't want this to sound like thoughtless retaliation, and I will respond to each point in kind, but first of all, assuming you've reproduced this e-mail verbatim, the fact that the author not only feels the need to *define* metacognition but also incorrectly refers to it as "meta-judgment" gives me the impression that this person just read the original Dunning-Kruger paper and has decided that s/he is seeing the pattern everywhere.  <sup>[citation needed]</sup> indeed.

Anyway, I said I'd respond to each point, so here goes:

1. I **reject** the notion that Wikipedia succeeds at this in the way that the author implies.  A quick look at their [list of controversial issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_controversial_issues) should quickly lay to rest any beliefs that every article is consistently unbiased and high-quality.  Wikipedia is not *bad* by any means, but there is a good reason why academia continues to refuse to allow it as a research source.
2. I **also reject** the notion that Stack Overflow is exclusively the domain of those whose metacognitive ability backs up each and every one of their votes.  Beginner questions do well, of course, but the more advanced/obscure the topic, the less reliable the information becomes.  Security is one area that I've noticed is often extremely weak.  Take, for example, the question about [how to store recoverable passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283937/how-should-i-ethically-approach-user-password-storage-for-later-plaintext-retriev/2290037#2290037); there is an answer with 47 upvotes advocating an approach that is *completely insecure* and making a *completely invalid* analogy to a system that actually *is* secure.  As with Wikipedia, Stack Overflow is not *bad* by any stretch of the imagination, but neither is it perfect even in its limited domain.
3. I **accept** the assertion that in order to survive in the long haul, we will need far more people from the cooking community as opposed to the programming community.  That is one reason why I asked a long time ago if we could get "crossover" statistics, i.e. find out how many members are new to SE and are not coming from SO or similar.  It goes without saying that as long as we have a fairly steady influx of users from SO and only a trickle from Google and WOM marketing, this will be a problem.  However, I have yet to see a QA thread so egregiously bad that it could seriously classify this effort as a *failure* or even anything close to it.
4. Generally speaking, there are actually many telltale signs of inadequate metacognitive ability and/or groupthink within a community.  The most obvious is a flurry of open-ended, loosey-goosey questions that anybody can participate in.  The Software Engineering proposal was stymied on Area 51 by this; the questions were *so obviously bad* that it was clear that the wrong people were participating.  That's why the name was changed to ACM/IEEE, to say "hey, this *might* be outside your area of expertise."  Not meaning to harp on the SE proposal here but what I'm trying to say is that it's *blindingly obvious* when the unskilled outnumber the skilled, and if you have to cherry-pick examples to "prove" it then it's probably not a real problem.
5. Cooking **is** subjective but not as subjective as some people make it out to be.  Many claims *are* testable, and presumably if somebody asked the question then they are going to test it.  There are several questions on the front page now with answers that are either obviously correct, easy to verify, or backed up by a source.  For example:

   - [What are the requirements for a dish to be kosher?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/7962/41) - backed up with Wikipedia source and would be easy to verify even without that.
   - My question the other day, [Why did my “Turkish Delight” turn into a horrible goopy mess?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/7951/41), is about a relatively obscure ingredient in North American cooking (agar).  Michael's theory was exactly correct and his suggestion to fix it worked.  I saw it happen; I was there!
   - [How do I control the temperature of burnt sugar?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/6732/41), another "advanced" question as far as typical home cooks are concerned, has an easily-testable answer and I can verify first-hand that the approach works.
   - One of the older, highly-voted questions is [what is the difference between white and brown eggs?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/3/41)  As usual, the answer which cannot be verified in the kitchen is backed up with a source.
   - In [How can you reduce the heat of a chili pepper?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/6620/41), the best answer outvoted the others by an entire order of magnitude, and although it is not sourced, it is blindingly simple to test.  If that is a subjective question then I am the president of France.

   And so on and so forth.  I admit that not every single answer actually has a citation, but to demonstrate that the site has a metacognition problem one has to show answers that are actually *wrong*, not just unsourced.
6. Even if our community does not have any more expertise than the myriad of other communities, as this anonymous e-mailer suggests, the engine gives it a major advantage over most other sites which are based on forums.  So if this person really believes that the site is collectively "ignorant", then that would be all the more reason **to** join, to help *fix* some of these issues, and recruit other knowledgeable people to do the same.  Everybody benefits from having a smarter community participating on a *site that doesn't suck.*

   What kind of person sends off an e-mail to say that a site is lousy and even goes so far as to admit that they've just lurked, instead of actually doing something constructive and making it better?  And why should we listen to what they have to say?

Anyway, to sum it up - to the question **Is cooking too subjective to work?** My answer is a big fat

## No.

If it were, we'd never have come this far.

Comment: "it's blindingly obvious when the unskilled outnumber the skilled" yahoo answers obvious perhaps? :)

Comment: how is babby^H^H^H^H^H stake formed?

Comment: On a more serious note, what Aaronut said is, as usual, on the nose. Perhaps more ominously, there is an... interesting progression from "What should the domain name be?" to "Here's the design we are ramming down your throat" to "No domain name sry" to "Can this site work?"

Comment: @roux a) you will have a domain name redirect b) I hardly think the design process is fairly characterized as "ramming" c) way off topic for this question, anyway

Comment: there is no other way to characterize 'here is a preliminary design concept' 'oh actually, this is the final design, enjoy' than 'ramming'. my point being, there has been a disturbing trend in announcements from on high.

Comment: @roux: I have to admit that I was a little suspicious of that too, but Cooking is one of the most successful SE sites *by the team's own metrics*, so let's give them the benefit of the doubt.  I think Jeff is doing the right thing by publicly airing such a major complaint and giving us the opportunity to respond.

Comment: @Jeff: I've come to realize that Yahoo Answers actually follows a similar pattern to other Q&A sites, if you think of the "subject" as "everything."  You actually *can* find good answers, but only to questions that are *very* basic - not with respect to a specific field but with respect to the general population. The narrower your scope, the less noise you get, but also the less traffic. It's really not an easy balance to strike, although clearly Yahoo had the wrong idea by virtue of the fact that there are  now several blogs dedicated exclusively to documenting the horrors there.

Answer (score 12):

Ah, prognosticating on The Internet - what could be more fun! As kids we pretended to be Matt Dillon; now we play Nostradamus.

By way of credentials, I shall reveal the following: I have predicted the Teletubby phenomenon, the rise of Google, the success of the iPhone, the victory of Hillary Clinton over Barack Obama in the 2008 US Presidential Primary Elections, and The Terrible Hummingbird Plague of 2009.

And I can confirm that Mr. Shalmanese is absolutely, *incontestably* correct in what he predicts:

- Ignorant brutes will descend upon the site, men of low pedigree will fill it with base answers and more will follow to greedily consume this vile offal, never mindful of its origin or the inauspicious name recommending it.
- The informed and enlightened will strive against this barbarousness, and find their words lumped in with barbecue stories and tips for making "eggs over easy". Bitter tears of frustration will flow like vinegar as they reflect on how, in another time, their pearls of wisdom might have lined bird cages or pressed flowers.
- Name-dropping will continue to be seen as a poor substitute for practical advice.

In addition, **I** predict that something *not* common to *every public forum in every medium ever* will occur. But I'll leave the exact nature of this to your imagination...

Comment: I wish I could flag "Ignorant brutes will descend upon the site, men of low pedigree will fill it with base answers" as _fucking awesome_.

Comment: I know I shouldn't +1 sarcasm as a complete answer, but +1 anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Since the author of that e-mail has come out and, among other things, suggested that we only do well for questions that are easily answered by Google already, allow me to provide a few counter examples:

1. [Why can applesauce be used in place of oil?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/6869/41)

   - I answered this one, and gave the actual (correct) explanation of why the substitution *sometimes* works, and heaped on disclaimers about the **limitations** of this substitution.  Perhaps it is not the most comprehensive answer on the web, but at least it tries to lead readers in the right direction.  The top 3 google results are full of inaccuracies.
   - The first result is a [chowhound](http://chowhound.chow.com/topics/352485) thread.  I've found that site to be very useful in the past, but the answers are all over the place.  The first two answers suggest a 1:1 substitution and that's almost *never* what you should do, even in a cake.  Only much later on (and who reads that far down?) do you start to hear that, actually, it really does change the taste and texture, and doesn't work in all baking recipes, and doesn't work so well when you've made the recipe from scratch as opposed to using a mix with all sorts of stabilizers, and that maybe you should go half-and-half or at least add a little bit of oil, and so on and so forth.  Not very authoritative at all.
   - The next result, from [eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_4535777_substitute-applesauce-oil.html), is slightly better in that it does mention some (not all) of the limitations.  However, it repeats the mantra that a 1:1 substitution is just fine without any other modifications.  It also adds some misleading statements at the bottom: "Unsweetened applesauce will reduce the amount of sugar in your recipe."  I *think* I understand what the author was getting at, but the way it's worded is backwards.  Adding even unsweetened applesauce may *increase* the total amount of sugar in a recipe, since apples are naturally sweet.  The more important point, which is never mentioned, is that using *sweetened* apple sauce will almost certainly require **you** to reduce sugar in *other* parts of the recipe to compensate.  A casual reader stumbling upon that eHow article would *not* take away that message.
   - And in third place we have an [Answers.com](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Can_you_substitute_apple_sauce_for_oil_butter_or_margarine_in_a_recipe) response, arguably the worst of them all, which suggests that you can substitute applesauce for butter or margarine (although, confusingly, it also says "in oil-based baked goods").  It does mention using *some* oil, so it gets a point for that, but mentions none of the other potential problems (sweetness, shape, etc.), and suggesting that applesauce would be a good substitute for butter in *bread* dough is *wrong wrong wrongity wrong.*
2. Just **try** using Google to find the answer to [Why do my muffin tops lean?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/4182/41)

   I'm sure that you consider this a basic question, but it is not so basic to everyone.  I've actually known a few people with this problem.  Using Google for this will get you nowhere, because both the word "lean" and the phrase "muffin top" are associated with body fat and weight loss, which, as you might expect, are several orders of magnitude more popular than muffin baking.
3. [Why do tomatoes get so hot?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/6287/41)

   I love this one because on what other cooking site would you get a physicist arriving to weigh in on the issue of heat distribution, conduction, and the difference between a food simply being hot and burning your mouth?  Perhaps you are looking for examples that are more about *culinary* techniques/issues, and I will get to those, but this is really an awesome question for demonstrating the usefulness of the whole SE "network" as opposed to individually-focused cooking forums.
4. [Why do some recipes recommend Kosher salt?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/2242/41)

   I've used kosher salt plenty of times in recipes but never knew half the stuff that Darin put in his answer.  That is, by and large, the most definitive post I've ever read on kosher salt.  It's way more useful than the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosher_salt) on it.
5. [Pasta: Simmering Water or Rolling Boil?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/3949/41)

   This is another one that I like, because it's a bit of a tricky issue.  We have two competing answers that are actually both sort of correct.  The accepted answer repeats the conventional wisdom but includes a proper explanation of all the terminology (including specific temperatures).  The other, higher-voted answer challenges the conventional wisdom and provides a source to back it up.  Both of these answers received many more votes than other answers.

   Now you might say "A-ha!  The accepted answer is wrong!  You see!"  Except it's *not* wrong.  The issue is that pasta does not *require* a huge pot or a rolling boil to cook perfectly.  But it's also true that especially for *certain* types of pasta, such as spaghetti, those factors do *help* if you tend toward leaving the pot unattended.  And that's exactly what the top answer says: "Help prevent sticking."  Nowhere does it repeat the erroneous folk wisdom that a simmer will turn the pasta into mush.

   Together these two answers provide a lot of insight that you just won't find on Google.  Most of the top results just parrot the myths.
6. [Frozen veggies meets gumbo = flavorless. How to add flavor?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/7136/41)

   I wouldn't even know where to begin searching for something like this on Google, and although Michael's answer seems obvious in hindsight, I think many if not most of us would not have thought of it soon enough to fix it (it's important to note that this answer came in *less than half an hour*).

So, do I need to go on, or is this sufficient to explain why our community and site is better than a Google search?

Obviously, like any site, there's going to be a long tail.  We're always going to have our share of [prosaic](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/5021/41) or even [mind-numbing](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/7921/41) questions, and sometimes they get voted up more than they should because they're easy to understand and people want Electorate badges.  But these kinds of questions are the staple of any cooking site.  *Many* home cooks have years of experience but are also self-taught and have gaps in their knowledge that a professional wouldn't have; many of these people also have valuable insights to contribute, and will be much more willing to do so if they can get their naïve questions answered without the smarmy attitude that so often accompanies the more "advanced" cooking communities.

And I would really like to see more advanced, "haute cuisine" questions here, but I think that will only come with time.  As I stated in my other answer, even on a site with *many* professionals such as Stack Overflow, the truly expert-level questions tend to get the least attention.  The only way to prevent that is to have a completely closed system that only allows recognized experts in the field, and then it starts to look more like an industry journal than a Q&A site.  We want to be useful to regular people too.

Answer (score 4):

It'd help if the author of the email could point to specific examples of

> I've been casually lurking on the cooking stack exchange for a while. It's awful.

"Everything sucks!" Is neither constructive nor actionable. I am still waiting for actual URL examples and explanations of what specifically is "awful" about cooking.stackexchange.com.

Provide URLs. Briefly explain what about them, exactly, is wrong.

Beyond "it's awful", even with examples, let's talk about positive examples: **you have to be able to point to other sites that you *do* think do things correctly**, or maybe aspects of different sites that work well.

The author, in his answer here, did cite http://forums.egullet.org/ and specifically http://forums.egullet.org/index.php?/topic/116617-sous-vide-recipes-techniques-equipment/ as examples of

> information resource that cannot be mimicked by any online and very few real world expertise sources

Though it's a bit of an [appeal to billionaire authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority) due to the participation of [Nathan Myrvold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nathan_Myhrvold) in the thread.

> sad for me seeing Quora turn from an absolutely amazing resource slowly into yet another internet community, exactly as I predicted when I interviewed with them ~6 months ago .. Joining the site and actively contributing will not be helpful if I believe the ultimate structure of the site is not geared for success.

Based on your Quora participation history, with friends like that, who needs enemies?

Still, it's useful to consider http://forums.egullet.org  as an example of a cooking Q&A (ish) site that is working.

Comment: eGullet is a great community with many great contributors.  The problem, as always, is that they're a forum, and a rather *large* one at that, and as such, most of what you see is noise.  But I'm sure I'm preaching to the choir here.

Comment: This is the nub of the issue I am pointing at. You don't know who Nathan Myhrvold even is. What's more, you aggressively don't *care* who he is. It's this Wikipedia style attitude that causes pathologies like danah boyd losing an argument on *how to spell her own name* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Danah_Boyd). The core of my argument is that this works somewhat acceptably on Wikipedia and SO. An answer can contain a reference you've never heard of but as long as you can verify it's correctness, you don't care about it's providence. This fundamentally does not work for cooking.

Comment: In cooking, providence *matters* deeply for Subject Matter Experts. That's something inherent in the process. Because cooking contains so much subjectivity and taste, I need to know where you're coming from to even be able to interpret your answer. Whether it's Alice Waters of David Chang matters deeply.

Comment: The only way serious, substantive discussions of Cooking can proceed is through a literate audience. One that is expected to learn and know these names and concepts and styles by default. If every discussion has to start from the basics known by a home cook, the discussion devolves into mediocrity.

Comment: @Shalmanese: What makes you think that any of us don't know or care who he is?  You're making all sorts of assumptions and claims without *any* evidence to support them, which is ironic in a discussion revolving around the ability to present evidence for subject matter.  All in all, it just sounds like you think we should all be oohing and aahing over the fact that *Nathan Myhvrold* posted, OMG!  Like I commented earlier, Alan Kay posted on Stack Overflow; so what?  Who cares?  In the grand scheme of things it meant almost nothing, SME or no.

Comment: Can you please tell me, without looking, how many times you think Nathan Myhvrold has posted in that thread? Can you also tell me, without looking, what you believe Nathan Myhvrold's contribution to the culinary realm has been?

Comment: @shalm I guess you never saw my danah boyd petition: http://www.ipetitions.com/petition/danahboydpropercase/index.html yep, it's really from me. http://anotherlab.rajapet.net/2008/06/sign-boyd-proper-case-petition.html

Comment: @Shalmanese: Again, *what does that have to do with anything?* Why should I try to answer these questions?  I don't care if God himself posted in that thread; you obviously think we should all be gushing over this whereas in reality it's the function of the community as a whole across many subjects and over a long period of time that actually matters, not a handful of contributions in a specific megathread by one or two celebrities.  As purported evidence of *how one site will succeed and another will fail*, your example falls *painfully* short, and it's silly to delve any deeper than that.

Comment: "In cooking, providence matters deeply for Subject Matter Experts." - Thank you for proving you are not, in fact, an SME when it comes to anything truly culinary. Those of us who _are_ professionals in the field only give a damn about provenance (the correct word) when it is coming from a known expert; Adria on hydrocollooids, or Robouchon on classic French, or Ripert on fish. Beyond that, the only thing we care about is if it _works_. Doesn't matter if it was Anne Burrell or the crazy guy down the street who said it. Does it work? Good.

Comment: @roux: You would be amazed at just how many deranged pantsless men in alleyways are actually brilliant ex-chefs, driven mad by the insane dietary restrictions of their clientele.  They're a veritable buffet of sound advice.

Comment: If I wanted sound advice, I'd talk to my techie friends. I want cooking advice ;)

Answer (score 4):

@Shalmanese: There's a critical piece of the philosophy and functionality that has eluded you: Stack Exchange's "archive of knowledge" is nowhere *near* finished in neither breadth nor depth. If the "depth" does not suit you, it will only continue to improve as new answers are contributed, existing answers are improved, and the whole collection is vetted and undergoes peer review.

You said that Stack Exchange is no different from the rest of them. That's high praise considering the Cooking Stack Exchange has barely existed for 90 days. So what if — at least in your opinion — Cooking.SE didn't snap into instant, unassailable genius in its first 90 days. That develops with time, hard work and continuing contribution.

But you chose to sit on the sidelines and watch and condemn.

In contrast, the forums you celebrate are constantly watered down and mired in irrelevance. Throw your "pearls of wisdom into an indifferent crowd"; Who's to know? Some of those questions are hundreds of pages long. What good are those pearls when there is so much noise to drown them out? How am *I* to find them?

If you fixed just *two* questions on this site, you would have improved this archive of knowledge by over 1%, single-handedly. That's quite an accomplishment for so little effort. —Small units of incremental impromement.

Comment: re: hundreds of pages long and noise, I found in those first answers to the "great example" things that were clearly said much better and debated more carefully here.  If it takes me pages and pages to get to the expert there and here I can find answers by professionals (roux, Darin, etc.) that bubble to the top through their exceptional quality, I'd stick with here even lacking authors of major monumental tomes at the moment!

Comment: @justkt - not to mention that Stack Overflow has been heralded as an example of where the formula works, but most of the top contributors there are only celebrities *on* Stack Overflow.  I won't pretend that we are "overflowing" here with professionals of the caliber of Nathan Myrvold or even Alton Brown, but the first step is getting professionals *period*.  Once you establish *that* reputation, the "giants" eventually take notice. I mean sure, Stack Overflow had [Alan Kay](http://stackoverflow.com/users/48710/alan-kay) come to make all of two posts; so what, did it really alter SO's destiny?

Comment: I made my prediction to the Quora people when that site was about the same age. I laid out exactly the arguments I'm laying out on this site now. They were unconvinced by them. I watched closely, I am slowly starting to see the effects I predicted take place. I engaged in a conversation with Jeff because I think the motivation behind SE is admirable but he is falling for the exact same unlearned lessons. If the community listens, that's great. If not, I have no actual affinity to this site or you people as users. It's not going to bring me joy to come back here in a year & say I told you so.

Comment: Part of the reason behind me stance on all of this is that this is not a new problem, it's a sickenly, depressingly old one. It's been happening over and over again in online communities for the last 20 years and the effects follow the same pattern every time.

Comment: @Shalmanese: Eventually, somebody is going to get it right, via technical means, which seems to have happened with Stack Overflow and may very well happen with these sites.  You haven't really explained *why* you think any of these sites are going to fail, other than "it's horrible", and if you're not going to offer constructive suggestions then what's the point in listening?

Answer (score 4):

I have trouble seeing the e-mail author's point at all.  In general the community has worked extremely hard to carefully craft a site definition that encourages good subjective questions which can be accurately judged by professionals and experienced amateurs and discourage the bad subjective.  For example we carefully defined what [recipes](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/746/are-recipe-requests-ok-if-they-are-fundamental-enough) might be objective enough that they could be correctly judged "the" recipe and therefore were acceptable on the site.  We've looked over what makes a [list of X](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/683/why-is-what-is-a-sub-for-parsley-ok-but-what-goes-with-green-tea-not) question acceptable and not [many](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/651/whats-the-difference-between-these-two-list-of-x-questions) [times](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/608/uses-of-x-questions-are-they-just-recipe-swaps-in-disguise), carefully debating who can verify whether or not a flavor pairing is good or not and other details, with our professional members and top contributors weighing in.  I think this has been largely successful in helping to define a very useful community where members seek answers that explain the why and how and information is shared in a generally constructive, informative, and fair tone.

I went looking for downvoted answers that were actually correct.  The closest thing I could find was [this response to changing a quick bread mix's sweetness](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7988/how-can-i-make-a-quick-bread-mix-less-sweet/7990#7990).  While the answer is technically correct, the discussion about the downvote gives a pretty clear defense of why the answer was voted down.  One could make a fairly good argument that it is not more correct than any higher voted answer.

I'm marking this CW - if you see anything else that could qualify for a worst answer as defined in the question, please fill it in.

Answer (score 4):

I know that at this late stage there's little point in adding another opinion to this, but still...

To me, the problem with Shalmanese is captured in this comment of his:

> In cooking, providence matters deeply
>   for Subject Matter Experts. That's
>   something inherent in the process.
>   Because cooking contains so much
>   subjectivity and taste, I need to know
>   where you're coming from to even be
>   able to interpret your answer.

First off, I think he means "provenance," but in any case this just amounts to an appeal to authority.  The people posting here don't meet his definition of established experts, therefor nothing they post can possibly be useful.  I strongly disagree with this attitude.

Yes, there's lots of subjectivity, but I don't rely on an expert to tell me what's good and bad, I can see it for myself.  I'm not a professional baker, but I've done enough and read enough books that I can make a pretty good cake and I can certainly tell a cake that tastes good from one that sucks w/out an expert to explain it to me.

I don't think cooking.se is that much different from Serverfault in that respect: most of my experience is w/ Windows, but I've used Unix and Linux enough that I can recognize a good answer from someone who is a Linux expert.

But basically Shalmanese thinks the site can't thrive with experienced amateurs posting, only if accredited professional chefs post.

Comment: The problem with citing logical fallacies is that they are as guilty of the lack of nuance as the fallacy they purport to demolish. Appealing to authority is _not_ a bad thing when what one wants is an authoritative answer; one doesn't ask a random person on the street how to set a broken bone, one asks a doctor.

Comment: However, as I said above, chefs really only care about provenance when you are talking about a specific subject in which someone has acclaimed expertise. Adria on hydrocolloids, as I said above, or Madhur Jaffrey on Indian cuisine, are likely to be seen as more authoritative answers when dealing within their subjects. I don't particularly care about Jaffrey's opinions on, say, how to bake croissants more or less than anyone with baking knowledge. If her methods work, that's all that matters.

Comment: Not only is the appeal to authority a disagreeable position here, but the *exact opposite* position has been enshrined in the design of SOFU and SE since day one.  Reputation is based on votes, and anyone can vote, thus one's reputation is (at least in theory) *proportional to one's direct contribution to the community* and not any other factors.  This works for mildly subjective issues too, as long as they aren't *so* subjective that no answer can actually be classified as wrong or unhelpful, and cooking is nowhere near *that* subjective.

Answer (score -9):

I am the author of that email and I welcome constructive debate. It's been a long time since I used the Stack * sites so excuse me if I fail to follow some point of social etiquette. The email thread arose out of a conversation around an essay I recently posted entitled ["The Evaporative Cooling Effect in Online Communities"](http://blog.bumblebeelabs.com/social-software-sundays-2-the-evaporative-cooling-effect/).

In response to Aaronut's post:

- Metacognition and Meta-judgement are two separate things. Metacognition is awareness of your *own* reasoning processes and relies on introspection. Meta-judgement is the assessment of someone else's contribution. These are two separate skills.
- I completely agree with you that Wikipedia has many, many problems. However, overall, they are largely successful. This is not what I'm arguing.
- I also completely agree that Stack Overflow is not perfect. This is also not what I'm arguing.
- You argue that Google/WOM is important and it obviously is but you've failed to articulate how, after you've reached out to people beyond the SO family, how you *convert* them into active participants. This is the crux of the issue.
- My concern is not with the level, it's with the first derivative. The question is can cooking exchange be built into a site that gets *better* over time? I don't see a mechanism for this to happen.
- Of the 5 examples Aaronut listed, 3 of them can have the exact same answer found as one of the first 3 hits in Google. This, IMO, is fine but not an especially compelling use of a Q&A site. The other two are genuinely good answers but they're not the type of *great* answers that make something an addicting resource. For an example of truly great answers, check out http://forums.egullet.org/index.php?/topic/116617-sous-vide-recipes-techniques-equipment/ for example. One of the most active contributors in that thread is Nathan Myhrvold, author of the new mega-tome on Molecular Gastronomy. In that thread, you see real, genuine Q&A going on and it's an information resource that cannot be mimicked by any online and very few real world expertise sources.
- As to what kind of person sends off an email complaining about a site, I'm a person who genuinely is invested in the SE mission and wants to see it succeed but I believe the best way of doing so is via informed critique. Joining the site and actively contributing will not be helpful if I believe the ultimate structure of the site is not geared for success. The other factor is that I'm one person with a limited number of hours in the day and I've already invested in a cooking site. I'm Shalmanese on eGullet and you probably recognize me there if you've spent any time there. If you imagine I or any other person in the world is going to see the site and immediately jump in with gusto, then that's a fundamentally flawed view. Instead, you should be asking, what it is about cooking exchange that could convince someone like me to *want* to make it a great resource.

Also, my main arguments have been on the downfall of Quora as they are coping with issues of growth and Cooking Exchange only incidentally came into the conversation as another community I expect to go down the same path. It's been extraordinarily sad for me seeing Quora turn from an absolutely amazing resource slowly into yet another internet community, exactly as I predicted when I interviewed with them ~6 months ago. The tricky issue is that, by the time you recognize the problem occurring, it's too late for the fix. What I'm arguing is not so much the state of cooking exchange now but what I see as it's inevitable state 12 months down the road if the same fundamental design is kept to.

Comment: The thread you listed is 129 pages long.  it might be full of great Q&A but how can I find it without reading through all of it which might contain a whole load of stuff I don't care about along side the answer to my query.  It's ok if you were involved in that from the start, but to come to the party late and you have a mammoth task ahead of you.

Comment: The second reply to the "great example" you linked to starts with "i laughed, i cried, it was better than cats, it changed my life forever".  I'm sorry, but if that's the best you can come up with, then you're just demonstrating why discussion forums don't work well as a teaching medium.  And "informed critique" would point to examples, not merely bash the community.  I didn't realize that you wanted to see examples that weren't easy to find on Google (considering part of the stated mission of SE is to *be the first Google result*), but I'm sure I can dig up several of those as well.

Comment: By the way, a Google search for "meta judgment" turns up not much of substance. I have never heard this term before. *Metacognition* is called *meta* cognition because it's *meta* - *knowing what you know*. The ability to assess someone else's contribution is not "meta-judgment", it's just *judgment*, and requires metacognitive ability. I am sorry if it seems like I'm quibbling over semantics here, but as you can see, I'm not using it as an excuse to ignore your larger points; I just think that, when making such a profound criticism, it helps to use either accepted jargon or plain English.

Comment: @Shalmanese - your e-mail indicates that you thinking cooking.se *is* currently awful.  Your last paragraph indicates that you think *it will be awful* in 12 months given the current structure.  Which is it and why - with examples, please.

Comment: @Sam, I aggree 100%. There is so much great information in that Sous Vide thread, but I've gotten so F#$%ING frustrated trying to find answers in that thread. It's impossible. And google doesn't help, because it finds a post that looks like it's a response to the answer you're trying to find, but you still can't find **that** post. eGullet has awesome information, but it's impossible to find if you're not part of the community and saw it happen in the first place. I think that's exactly the issue that SE is supposed to solve!

Comment: It *is exactly* the issue that SE is supposed to solve, @yossarian. The team has stated in the past and restated recently that Google is the "Front Page" for SOFU/SE. I participate and even moderate some traditional discussion forums too, so I'm keenly aware of the differences; the one thing I've come to hate the most about forums is exactly what you refer to, the "I guess you had to be there" feeling, where putting any one post into context means that you have to painstakingly read the entire thread. And of course most people don't bother and just post anyway, further polluting the waters.

Comment: The eGullet SV page is widely known as one of the two or three best resources for SV on the internet and, for a long time, was one of the single best written documentations of SV that existed anywhere in the world. Seeing people here dismiss it as a 129 page long, hard to navigate is as laughable as saying here "Oh El Bulli? That can't be a very good restaurant. It's super hard to get to. What we should do is build a 3 michelin star restaurant but in Barcelona so that it is easier to get to". If you start from this base of general cluelessness, you have no hope of attracting true SMEs.

Comment: What a patently ridiculous analogy.  That thread is more like going to what is supposed to be a 3-star restaurant but finding that their menu has been scrambled and hidden inside a collage of children's crayon drawings, bad comic books, and pages from *Atlas Shrugged*.  And you have to sign 30 pages of Terms and Conditions in order to place an order.

Comment: Separately, whenever somebody says that something is "widely known", that's a sure sign that they're not prepared to back it up.  I don't know, *maybe* it had the status you describe, before it reached critical mass and everybody and their brother started posting in it.  But now I can only describe it as an inscrutable mishmash of good recipes, mediocre recipes, random tips and techniques, in-jokes and pointless banter.  It's incoherent and you know it.  Holding that up as an example of a *great* source of information is only weakening your position here.

Comment: No, when I'm a subject matter expert and I say that El Bulli is one of the best restaurants in the world and the other person says "wait, I don't know if that's true, can you prove that", my correct response is to stop wasting my time talking to that person. It's not going to be a productive conversation and I have better uses for my time. Similarly, if you ask any SME in Sous Vide from 2005 - 2008 like, say, Dave Arnold, what are the best resources for learning Sous Vide, they would say...

Comment: "It sucks, there's barely any good resources. There's Roca's book, some stuff by Khymos and that shitty eGullet thread." I might be wrong on the actual substance of the answer, I'm not a Sous Vide SME but I at least know enough to recognize someone who is (meta-judgement). Feel free to empirically validate this by actually asking an actual SME this question. I'm pretty sure that eGullet thread will come up.

Comment: The reason that thread could have been created there and could not have been created here is that, in the eGullet thread, once you got past the 8th page or so, you could go in there and make a random obscure assertion without support and if it was correct, it would pass without comment. If it was incorrect, a SME would reply with "I think this is bullshit, can you back that up. Here, if I were to come in and make a random obscure assertion without support and I was correct, the community would respond with "I'm not sure about this, can you back that up?" and if I was incorrect, they would...

Comment: respond with "I'm not sure about this, can you back that up?"

Comment: Because I am innately curious, I did indeed spend the time trying to back up my assertion and I found this: http://blog.khymos.org/2009/01/18/a-mathematician-cooks-sous-vide/ which pretty convincingly proves my point IMHO. But, in order to do so, I had to spend 5 minutes trawling Google, just to confirm that I do, indeed know what the fuck I'm talking about. I actually forgot about Doug Baldwin in my answer but I would have definitely recognized the name if it had been suggested. But this is my point, SMEs do not put up with this shit. I'm only doing so because I'm a pigheaded asshole.

Comment: That I'm being treated this way despite me being not even a very high quality contributor is a pretty good dissection of why this site utterly fails at attracting high quality contributors and is doomed to failure.

Comment: A lot of us here consider ourselves to have varying degrees of expertise on the subject matter. The Dunning-Kruger effect swings both ways and I'm inherently mistrustful of people who outwardly claim to be experts without any credentials to show for it. So if your position is that we are simply to take your word for it because you are an SME, then I am forced to reject that argument on said basis. You want to know what wasting time is? Leveling broad but serious criticisms without being able to point to any specific examples or offer constructive suggestions, even after being given ample time.

Comment: You are not a SME in Sous Vide. Objectively, I can claim that. If you ended up in a genuine encounter with a true SME in Sous Vide, 99% of the time, you would "win" in that you would have the last word in the argument but lose in that Cooking Exchange would never have that SME as a contributor because they cannot see the point. I'm done with this conversation.

Comment: @Shalmanese - as someone who claims not to be an SME on an area, you are judging another person's expertise?  Interesting.  So far for your own credentials you have provided active participation in a forum that is frequented by some notable people in the culinary world.  Perhaps you could back yourself up by providing your own credentials - as well as the specifics we all keep asking for.  So far all I see is "this isn't already an insider's club."  Yet if you wanted to see the insider conversation flying, you'd actually be seeing "bad subjective" as defined by SO - unverified info.

Comment: Umm. You go from "I welcome constructive debate" to, "[I know] what the fuck I'm talking about", "put up with this shit", and "I'm a pigheaded asshole". With that attitude the quality of your contributions is irrelevant. Pack your stuff and leave.

Comment: @Shalmanese: You're right, I'm not an expert on sous-vide.  I don't do any sous-vide whatsoever.  In case you hadn't noticed, this site is not about sous-vide, it's about the whole of cooking, and it's *very* hard for someone to be an expert on all things culinary.  Even with all that said, you can't *objectively* claim a damn thing because you don't know me.  And if you are claiming to be the "SME" yourself, then prove it, either by credentials or by actual contributions (no wai!).  Otherwise your assertions are meaningless.

Comment: And after all this you *still* can't point to a single specific example of what you think is wrong with this site.  I can only assume at this point that you have none.

Comment: Can we just call this what it is, troll, and move on please? This reeks of "my daddy can beat up your daddy!" Dude had a complaint, it was rightly aired by jeff, we all seem to disagree with him, he's not making compelling arguments, lets bury it.

Comment: Yep, boring. Darwin will decide whether this site ultimately has a lot of value or not, we don't really need to debate it... just keep doing it and see if it grows or withers.